# Why am I unable to change my skin?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have already bought the PC version on minecraft for my account. However, when attempting to change my skin, the game simply states:"You have to buy the PC edition of Minecraft."

Which is odd because I already have.

**Why is this happening? How can I fix it?**

Comment: Hi welcome to Arqade. It would be helpful if you include more information in your question. Such as, did you attempt to change your skin using minecraft.net? Or an external method? Are you able to log into your minecraft account and play on servers?

Answer (score 2):

To change your skin, go to [minecraft.net](http://minecraft.net) and hit "log in." Once you've logged in, go to "profile" and there will be an option to set your skin. While there are other ways of setting your skin, they are not all reliable. Also ensure that you are using the correct email address if you are using a migrated account.

Comment: This information did not help. When I logged in there was a button that said "Edit Profile, so i clicked it and there was nothing that said "set your skin" I i migrated my account it still won't work I don't Know why and I'm stuck with my skin. I tried to reset it but to my original Steve/Alex skin but that won't even work.